# evaluating a differential

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The differential of of a function is 
$$
dz=(2x+3y)\,dx+(3x-2y)\,dy
$$
$X$ varies between $2$ and $2.05$, 
$Y$ varies between $3$ and $3.05$.

I know that $\Delta z=0.6449$.

But how do I evaluate that from above equation?

Where what I tried is
$$
\Delta z=(2x+3y)\,\Delta x+(3x-2y)\, \Delta y,
\ \Delta x=0.05,
\ \Delta y=-0.04.
$$
Now I substitute $x=2$ and $y=3$
$$
\Delta z=(2\cdot 2+3\cdot3) \Delta x+(3\cdot2-2\cdot3)\,\Delta y=13\,\Delta x=0.65. 
$$
What I didn't do right?

Comment: Do you mean $Y$ varies between $3$ and $2.96$ instead? 

If that is the case, then
$$dz = (2 x + 3y)dx + (3x - 2y)dy = d(x^2+3xy-y^2)$$
leads to
$$\begin{align}
\Delta z 
&= \Delta(x^2+3xy-y^2)\\
&= ( 2.05^2 + 3(2.05)(2.96) - 2.96^2 ) - (2^2 + 3(2)(3) - 3^2)\\
&= 0.6449
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @EWHLee thanks for editing but could you answer my question? What is the better place to learn to edit jmath?

Comment: @achillehui yes that is the case for Y. And how do I evaluate dz, like I did above?

Comment: $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ is finite, you need to keep the quadratic terms $\Delta x^2, \Delta x\Delta y$ and $\Delta y^2$ to get the right $\Delta z$. An alternate way to get $\Delta z$ has been given in previous comment. Namely, directly evaluate the difference of the expression $x^2 + 3xy - y^2$ between $(x,y)$ and $(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)$.

Comment: @kelly: Posting math here is routine for me because I am a TeX user. I don't think you need to learn TeX just to post. But by reading a few examples and posting a few questions (while watching the preview screen) yourself, you should get the hang of it.

Comment: @achillehui  maybe what I should have wrote was evaluating Δz makes sense , but does it make sense evaluating dz? For me it doesn't but I read that could be a mistake

Comment: Yes, it does make sense to evaluate $dz$ but to properly understand what that means, that is not the material for first year calculus. At this moment, you should treat $dz$ simply as some notations which help you manipulate the formulas.